# How to find the decision corresponding to a patent on ESPACENET?

Tags: patent-services

I was reading [EP 1 207 394 A2](http://worldwide.espacenet.com/publicationDetails/biblio?DB=EPODOC&II=0&ND=3&adjacent=true&locale=en_EP&FT=D&date=20020522&CC=EP&NR=1207394A2&KC=A2) filed in 2001, so I believe there could be a decision available. How can I find it?

Answer (score 2):

I assume by "a decision" you are asking if it has reached a final disposition. It has resulted in a patent.

If you go to that document in ESPACENET you will see an "also published as" box. In it is a link to a publication with the same number but followed by B1. That designation is for an issued patent. If you follow that link you get to the issued patent.

[image]

In the upper left see "Date of publication and mention of grant of patent"

Comment: Ok. So I checked under the decisions from December 2009 (http://www.epo.org/law-practice/case-law-appeals/recent/2009.html#200912). Should I be able to find the patent grating report there? Or can I only find reports on not-granted patents there?